# Data virtualization using DynamicData

Tags: c#, wpf, virtualization, dynamic-data, reactiveui

I'm looking for an example on how to virtualise data using DynamicData (version 16.17.14).

On the GitHub page this snippet is shown:

```
IObservable<IVirtualRequest> request; //request stream
var virtualisedStream = someDynamicDataSource.Virtualise(request)
```

But how do I initialize the `request` parameter?

I have found old examples that use the class `VirtualisingController` from the package DynamicData.ReactiveUI but it looks like those don't exist anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VirtualisingController` was removed several years ago. It was replaced directly by `IObservable<IVirtualRequest>`.

The easiest way to instantiate the observable is to use a subject:

`var myRequests = new BehaviorSubject<IVirtualRequest>(new VirtualRequest(0,50))`

and call `myRequests.Onnext(...)` to change the values. The behavior subject is required to pass an intitial value into the virtual operator.

The controller was an abstraction on the behavior subject, which I introduced in a very early version of Dynamic Data but removed it in favour of using an observable directly.